# ImmutableList does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, immutable-collections

I'm trying to initialize an immutable list like a regular list, but it's telling me it doesn't take 0 arguments. It throws the same error if I pass 1 argument, 2 arguments, etc.

```
public static readonly ImmutableList<object[]> AddressTestCases = new ImmutableList<object[]>
{
    new object[]{ "", false },
    new object[]{ "testestest", true },
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to do this without using .Add?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is using a constructor that doesn't exist. Pass the set of objects you want in the list to the constructor.

Comment: If the constructor doesn't exist, how do you pass a set of object to it? It doesn't work with 1 argument, 2, etc. either. It throws the same error.

Comment: Like the error states, `ImmutableList does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`. You need to use the constructor that takes one argument, i.e. the one that takes a list of objects.

Comment: `ImmutableList does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments` Then I get this error, I tried just passing `null`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok [ImmutableList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456042(v=vs.111).aspx) has a create method that you should be using

```
public ImmutableList<int> ImmutableListCreate()
{
    return ImmutableList.Create<int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an ImmutableList you have to use the static factory method Create() defined on the ImmutableList static class.

This means you will need

```
public static readonly ImmutableList<object[]> AddressTestCases = 
    ImmutableList.Create(new object[] { "", false }, new object[] { "testtest", true });
```

Answer (score -1):

The syntax you are using is *not* calling the constructor you think it is. It is calling the empty constructor and then n the background calling `.Add` for the object arrays you gave.

You will need to use one of the builder methods:

```
public static readonly ImmutableList<object[]> AddressTestCases =
                          new[] {
                                   new object[]{ "", false }, 
                                   new object[]{ "testestest", true }
                                }).ToImmutableList();
```

Comment: [`ImmutableList<T>` has no public constructors.](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Oops, true.